# Необходимо удалить сторно и сторнирующие продажи

Tags: python, алгоритм

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Дана таблица продаж сопутствующих товаров на разных АЗС объемом 713745 строк.
Необходимо удалить "минусовые" чеки и продажи, которые они отменяют (номера чеков разные).

Условия:

1. за день может быть несколько одинаковых продаж (товар, магазин, кол-во, сумма продаж и т.п.). Поэтому через удаление дубликатов не получится.
2. строка с минусовым чеком не обязательно следует за соответствующей продажей. Я хотела вычислить по индексу строки, подлежащие удалению (составить список индексов минусовых чеков, отнять от каждого значения единицу и получить список индексов строк, подлежащих удалению).

Часть датасета для понимания структуры и тренировки можно посмотреть здесь:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gPHbUQTGVAfUGOeEQbAgCGRlgnXoHZ4v/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107408597853648006127&rtpof=true&sd=true

Заранее благодарю!!!

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143246/discussion-on-question-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Всем добрый день!
Еще раз благодарна за отклик.

Решила свою задачу через merge. Получилось пусть не очень изящно, но результат нужный. Структуру тестового файла изменила, добавив столбец с временем чека.

1. Разбила исходный датафрейм на 2: продажи и возвраты
2. Преобразовала отрицательные значения в датафрейме с возвратами
3. Изменила названия столбцов time и receipt в датафрейме с возвратами, чтобы они не участвовали в pd.merge
4. Присоединила продажи к возвратам (how = left)
5. Оставила строки, в которых время возврата больше времени продажи
6. Удалила дубликаты по необходимым столбцам, оставив последний (keep = 'last')
7. Привела структуру получившегося датафрейма в соответствии со структурой по продажам
8. Присоединила к продажам: sales = sales.append(storno1, ignore_index=True)
9. Удалила дубликаты (keep = False)

Ссылка на ноутбук:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UCxUm4i2uPlrcgiRLeDq0rCwyyM1RePe/view?usp=sharing

Ссылка на тестовые данные:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hRZZ7EBhyVsbLvy4x5fva7ZtkUCvl1bt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Да не надо было "общий" ответ ставить, вы проделали большую работу )

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо за "большую работу") Пусть кому-то это поможет. В следующий раз вспомню ваш совет!